# Override Sonata Users services Menu Group

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I make user of the Sonata User Bundle. According to the documentation under section [2.5 Extending the Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html#extending-the-bundle) they want me to generate a complete new bundle for my user and group entities. I think this is completely unnecessary and I don't want that extra bundle. So I've created my User and Group entities in my AppBundle and I extend them from the Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser entities.

After this, I've changed my fos_user user_class and group_class to my new entities.

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     AppBundle\Entity\User

    group:
        group_class:   AppBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

Everything works perfectly, my user and group tables in my database is generated correctly, I can create users through the fos user command line, and I can log in.

In the menu is an automatically generated user group that contain the user and group entities (see the image below). Now the only problem is to override the services for this entities to them to use my own entity classes, because when I click now on one of them they want the entities in the extended bundle that I don't want. How can I tell sonata to make use of my own services? Or even, how can I just remove or hide the Users (with Users and Groups) completely?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging in Sonata User Bundle files, I see that the entities can be set with a parameter. So all I had to do was to add;

```
parameters:
    sonata.user.admin.user.entity: AppBundle\Entity\User
    sonata.user.admin.group.entity: AppBundle\Entity\Group
```

in my config.yml file.

Answer (score 2):

> "Or even, how can I just remove or hide the Users (with Users and Groups) completely?"

So, we have SonataUserBundle and our AppBundle. 
In both of them we have User and Group Entity. And we don't want to use entities from sonata - we just extend them. But SonataUserBundle has already had the UserAdmin and GroupAdmin classes inside. 
That's why, after installing SonataUserBundle in the admin menu appear two services:

[image]

As you know, every sonata admin class we declare in the services.yml file. 
In SonataUserBundle we have another files, which sonata developers declare services in. In case of using doctrine orm we should look at admin_orm.xml file, which lies in this path:

```
vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Resources/config/admin_orm.xml
```

Inside the file we can find the declaration of the admin services - UserAdmin and GroupAdmin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services     http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <parameters>
    <parameter     key="sonata.user.admin.groupname">sonata_user</parameter>
        <parameter     key="sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue">SonataUserBundle</parameter>
        <parameter key="sonata.user.admin.groupicon"><![CDATA[<i class='fa fa-users'></i>]]></parameter>
</parameters>
<services>
    <service id="sonata.user.admin.user" class="%sonata.user.admin.user.class%">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="%sonata.user.admin.groupname%" label="users" label_catalogue="%sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" icon="%sonata.user.admin.groupicon%"/>
        <argument/>
        <argument>%sonata.user.admin.user.entity%</argument>
        <argument>%sonata.user.admin.user.controller%</argument>
        <call method="setUserManager">
            <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager"/>
        </call>
        <call method="setTranslationDomain">
            <argument>%sonata.user.admin.user.translation_domain%</argument>
        </call>
    </service>
    <service id="sonata.user.admin.group" class="%sonata.user.admin.group.class%">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="%sonata.user.admin.groupname%" label="groups" label_catalogue="%sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"/>
        <argument/>
        <argument>%sonata.user.admin.group.entity%</argument>
        <argument>%sonata.user.admin.group.controller%</argument>
        <call method="setTranslationDomain">
            <argument>%sonata.user.admin.group.translation_domain%</argument>
        </call>
    </service>
</services>
```

As you can see here the ids of our services:

```
sonata.user.admin.user
sonata.user.admin.group
```

The simplest method to overwrite them is to create the same services (I mean we will use this ids ) in our services.yml file. 
Yes, you  can have an argument with me, that this method is stupid, but as I said it's not the only one.

So Sonata services in OUR services.yml will looks like this:

```
sonata.user.admin.user:
    class: "%sonata.user.admin.user.class%"
    arguments: [~, "%sonata.user.admin.user.entity%", "%sonata.user.admin.user.controller%"]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "%sonata.user.admin.groupname%", label_catalogue: "%sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue%", label: "users", icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-users\"></i>" }
    calls:
        - [ setUserManager, [ "@fos_user.user_manager" ] ]
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [ "%sonata.user.admin.user.translation_domain%" ] ]

sonata.user.admin.group:
    class: "%sonata.user.admin.group.class%"
    arguments: [~, "%sonata.user.admin.group.entity%", "%sonata.user.admin.group.controller%"]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "%sonata.user.admin.groupname%", label_catalogue: "%sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue%", label: "groups" }
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [ "%sonata.user.admin.group.translation_domain%" ] ]
```

Now you can update the admin dashboard and see, that nothing have happened. But the our purpose was to disable this service from our dashboard and menu. Let's do the trick. Add

```
show_in_dashboard: false
tags:
        - { show_in_dashboard: false, name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "%sonata.user.admin.groupname%", label_catalogue: "%sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue%", label: "users", icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-user\"></i>" }
```

to the declaration of this service in services.yml.

Therefore our services will look like this:

```
sonata.user.admin.user:
    class: "%sonata.user.admin.user.class%"
    arguments: [~, "%sonata.user.admin.user.entity%", "%sonata.user.admin.user.controller%"]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "%sonata.user.admin.groupname%", label_catalogue: "%sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue%", label: "users", icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-user\"></i>", show_in_dashboard: false }
    calls:
        - [ setUserManager, [ "@fos_user.user_manager" ] ]
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [ "%sonata.user.admin.user.translation_domain%" ] ]

sonata.user.admin.group:
    class: "%sonata.user.admin.group.class%"
    arguments: [~, "%sonata.user.admin.group.entity%", "%sonata.user.admin.group.controller%"]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "%sonata.user.admin.groupname%", label_catalogue: "%sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue%", label: "groups", show_in_dashboard: false }
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [ "%sonata.user.admin.group.translation_domain%" ] ]
```

After this trivial manipulations Sonata services will completely disappear from your Dashboard.